# Packaging Program in JAR

Tags: java, jar

I have written my first project in java, but I have many doubts to create a jar file from the console (I do not use any IDE to learn better).

The structure of my "Ahorcado" project is this:

```
jcv@vant ~/Proyectos/Ahorcado $ tree
.
├── bin
│   ├── Ahorcado$1.class
│   ├── Ahorcado.class
│   └── misClases
│       ├── Juego.class
│       ├── Sound.class
│       ├── Sound$Volume.class
│       ├── WindowAbout.class
│       ├── WindowHelp.class
│       └── WindowMessage.class
├── config
├── icon.png
├── META-INF
│   └── MANIFEST.MF
├── README.txt
├── res
│   ├── fonts
│   │   └── tiza.ttf
│   ├── img
│   │   ├── 1.png
│   │   ├── 2.png
│   │   ├── 3.png
│   │   ├── 4.png
│   │   ├── 5.png
│   │   ├── 6.png
│   │   ├── 7.png
│   │   ├── derrotas.png
│   │   ├── donate.gif
│   │   ├── icon128.png
│   │   ├── icon256.png
│   │   ├── pista.png
│   │   └── triunfos.png
│   └── media
│       ├── acierto.wav
│       ├── error.wav
│       ├── gameover.wav
│       └── victoria.wav
├── run.bat
├── run.sh
└── src
    ├── Ahorcado.java
    └── misClases
        ├── Juego.java
        ├── Sound.java
        ├── WindowAbout.java
        ├── WindowHelp.java
        └── WindowMessage.java
```

Compile with:

```
javac -d bin -cp src src/Ahorcado.java
```

And I run with:

```
java -cp bin Ahorcado
```

When I try to create the jar file, I have two doubts:

What is the command to create an executable jar file? I try something like that but I'm not sure:

```
jar cfvm ahorcado.jar ./META-INF/MANIFEST.MF ./bin/ res config
```

What should be the content of the MANIFEST.MF file? I try this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: bin.Ahorcado
```

But this does not work:

```
java -jar ahorcado.jar
```

EDIT:

It seems that it is better this way:

```
jar cfvm ahorcado.jar ./META-INF/MANIFEST.MF -C ./bin/ . res config
```

And in the file MANIFEST.MF:

```
Main-Class: Ahorcado
```

Although running the jar does not find the files in the res and config directories

Comment: *does not find the files*: what is your code? If you're using file IO (i.e. File, FileInputStream, FileReader, etc.), that can't possibly work, since these are not files on the file system anymore, but resources inside a jar file on the classpath. You need to use Class.getResourceAsStream().

Comment: You should use a build system (gradle, maven, ant), unless like avoiding an IDE, you do that to learn.

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet, I was using FileInputStream, but I've already realized that I must use Class.getResource(). I posted the code at https://github.com/Webierta/AhorcadoJavaFx
I keep working on it ...